# cite an answer or an image

Tags: discussion

I want to use an image from this thread to my Thesis.

[Images with all colors](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22144/images-with-all-colors?newreg=4b9ff227e08e461bb59fe83706ae18b2)

How can cite it.

Comment: Important and related: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The StackExchange network requires people who post questions and answers to grant them a licence: this is necessary because otherwise they could potentially be infringing copyright by serving up the questions and answers to other users. The practical implementation of this involves a licence called "CC BY-SA 3.0 with attribution required", and that licence effectively allows StackExchange to sublicense the content.

However, it's not an exclusive licence. If you want to use a single image for your thesis, it's probably worth posting a comment on the relevant answer asking whether the owner is willing to negotiate a separate licence for that purpose. I expect that most users would be honoured by such a request and happy to agree.

Two things to be aware of:

1. It might be worth thinking about how you would prefer to attribute the image (i.e. the format which fits the bibliographic standard you're following) and including a concrete suggestion in your initial request.
2. The owner might prefer to be cited using their real name, but communicating that real name to you by private e-mail, so you may have to give them an e-mail address. Think about whether you want to expose your general e-mail address, or whether you want to use a throwaway one which you don't mind exposing publicly.

Comment: Alternatively, just license the thesis under CC-BY-SA and add a link back to the post (which is the attribution required by SE), and all requirements are automatically fulfilled. (I am not a lawyer.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is on topic for this site, but here's a link that may be useful: [Citing websites and databases using harvard referencing](https://student.unsw.edu.au/how-do-i-cite-electronic-sources).
The second one down 'To cite a page or document  within a website' seems to be what you're after.

Comment: I'm looking explenations like the following
http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1273/how-can-we-make-citing-askubuntu-easier
http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6338/when-citing-another-user-how-should-her-his-username-be-formatted
http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/71/citation-feature